# Display only equivalent to masked input (javascript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In various places in our web app we have the following

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => gridRow.data.IdExternal, new { @class = "ref-format" })
```

where ref-format is defined like so:

```
<script src="../../../../Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js"  type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".ref-format").mask("99/99/99999", { placeholder: "n" });
</script>
```

I'd like to use this display mask for a straight display of a field value. On the off chance, I put the ref-format javascript in the relevant page, then tried this, but doesn't work, which makes sense since it's not an input box..

```
<div class="display-field highlight01 ref-format">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Token.Reference)</div>
```

just rendered as (e.g.)

```
<div class="display-field highlight01 ref-format">
    000700882
</div>
```

and appears as "000700882" with no slashes.

My question is - how do I best mask the displayed data with the same mask as the input box? I'm new to both javascript and MVC (though that latter is not the issue).

oh and if it matters

```
div.display-field {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    max-width: 70%;
    width: 69%;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: Just a thought, why don't you mask the value in an input box and then apply a css style which would make it look like a label?

Comment: I believe masking is only possible on input elements and not on inner text of a container element. I tried following code and it does the masking `<input style="border:none; background-color:transparent;" disabled="disabled" type="text" id="otherdate" value="01012015" />`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing an extension method to do the formatting and using @Html.Raw

```
<div class="display-field highlight01">@Html.Raw(Model.Token.Reference.FormattedReference())</div>
```